# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' in Xamarin.UWP

Tags: serialization, xamarin.forms, json.net, xamarin.uwp

I have a project in Xamarin.Forms I'm using following line to parse the JSON to object.

var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultstringjson);

It works properly in Xamari.Android and Xamarin.iOS but when I'm running it in UWP it shows following error.

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Does any one have idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives` to you `project.json` file in your UWP project directly, like this:

```
"dependencies": {
     "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives":  "4.0.10-*"
}
```

Comment: Here the System.Runtime.Serialization is there in bin folder but version is different 4.6.*.* . Do you know how can I cahange it?

Comment: I am able to fix the issue. Since I was using old datacontracts from legacy application it was causing the issue so I moved to new ones